# Linux mint GRUB issue

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I installed linux mint 12 and when I restared 'No such partition ' messgae came and entered into 'Grub rescue' mode.I entered commands and booted successfully.

How to repair GRUB now?

Because everytime I reboot I go into GRUB rescue mode.

Answer (score 0):

## Simplest Way to Repair Grub:

Run The Following Command:

```
 sudo apt-get update grub
```